# ECDSA Key pair generation output error

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography

I tried the below code to generate the key pair, but it prints the 8 byte data which is nothing but memory address. Could anybody shed light on what is the issue, how to print the 256 bit/32 byte private key & its corresponding public key

I am running the program in VS 2010 & installed openssl win32 & also linked openssl in my project properties.

output data:

Private key: 00156C90

Public key: 00158cc0

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main()
    {
    //EC_KEY* key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp224r1);
    //EC_KEY* key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
        EC_KEY* key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);


    if(!key)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error creating curve key" << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if(!EC_KEY_generate_key(key))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error generating curve key" << '\n';
        EC_KEY_free(key);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    BIGNUM const* prv = EC_KEY_get0_private_key(key);
    if(!prv)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error getting private key" << '\n';
        EC_KEY_free(key);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }



    std::cout << "Private key: " << prv << '\n';

    EC_POINT const* pub = EC_KEY_get0_public_key(key);
    if(!pub)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error getting public key" << '\n';
        EC_KEY_free(key);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    std::cout << "Public key: " << pub << '\n';


    // Use keys here ...

    EC_KEY_free(key);


    }
```

Comment: you are printing the pointer, not the key, if you know the length you sould print from the pointer.begin to pointer.begin+lenght, but since i havent worked with this lib i don't know if with that would be enough

Answer (score 0):

You should use the corresponding functions to display the `BIGNUM` and `EC_POINT` values:

---

In the [bn documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/bn.html):

> The basic object in this library is a `BIGNUM`. It is used to hold a single large integer. **This type should be considered opaque** and fields should not be modified or accessed directly.

and

> The conversion of `BIGNUM`s to external formats is described in `BN_bn2bin`.

Where we find [`BN_bn2hex()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/BN_bn2bin.html) which can be used to print out the hexadecimals of the private key (hexadecimals are commonly used for keys).

---

Similarly, there is `EC_POINT_point2hex` defined for [EC_POINT_new](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EC_POINT_new.html) (`_new` is just the first function of many defined for that man page). It doesn't clearly specify what point representation is used.

Comment: OpenSSL's documentation remains a mess, it doesn't specify the exact output format for `EC_POINT`. Please try the function and - if at all possible - update my answer with the correct format. If it starts with `04` then it is probably an uncompressed EC key, otherwise it may just be X and Y concatenated, for instance.